# Process lots of small tasks and keep the UI responsive

Tags: wpf, system.reactive, dispatcher, reactiveui

I have a WPF application that needs to do some processing of many small tasks.
These small tasks are all generated at the same time and added to the Dispatcher Queue with a priority of Normal. At the same time a busy indicator is being displayed. The result is that the busy indicator actually freezes despite the work being broken into tasks.

I tried changing the priority of these tasks to be Background to see if that fixed it, but still the busy indicator froze.

I subscribed to the `Dispatcher.Hooks.OperationStarted` event to see if any render jobs occurred while my tasks were processing but they didn't.

Any ideas what is going on?

Some technical details:
The tasks are actually just messages coming from an `Observable` sequence, and they are "queued" into the dispatcher by a call to ReactiveUI's `ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)` which should be equivalent to `ObserveOn(DispatcherScheduler)`. The work portion of each of these tasks is the code that is subscribing through the ObserveOn call e.g.

```
IObservable<TaskMessage> incomingTasks;
incomingTasks.ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler).Subscribe(SomeMethodWhichDoesWork);
```

in this example, incomingTasks would produce maybe 3000+ messages in short succession, the ObserveOn pushes each call to SomeMethodWhichDoesWork onto the Dispatcher queue so that it will be processed later

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The basic problem

The reason you are seeing the busy indicator stall is because your `SomeMethodWhichDoesWork` is taking too long. While it is running, it prevents any other work from occuring on the Dispatcher.

Input and Render priority operations generated to handle animations are lower than Normal, but higher priority than Background operations. However, operations on the Dispatcher *are not interrupted by the enqueing of higher priority operations*. So a Render operation will have to wait for a running operation, even if it is a Background operation.

### Caveat regarding observing on the DispatcherScheduler

`ObserveOn(DispatcherScheduler)` will push everything through at Normal priority by default. More recent versions of Rx have on overload that allows you to specify a priority.

One point to highlight that's often missed is that items will be queued onto the Dispatcher by the DispatcherScheduler as soon as they arrive **NOT** one after the other.

So if your 3000 items all turn up fairly close together, you will have 3000 operations at Normal priority backed up on the Dispatcher blocking everything of the same or lower priority until they are done - including Render operations. This is almost certainly what you were seeing - and that means you might still see problems even if you do all but the UI update work on a background thread depending on how heavy your UI updates are.

In addition to this, you should check you aren't running the whole subscription on the UI thread - as Lee says. I usually write my code so that I `Subscribe` on a background thread rather than use SubscribeOn, although this is perfectly fine too.

### Recommendations

Whatever you do, do as much work as possible on a background thread. That point has been done to death on StackOverflow, and elsewhere. Here are some good resources covering this:

- [MSDN Entry on WPF Threading Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx)
- [MSDN Magazine "Build More Responsive Apps With The Dispatcher", by Shaun Wildermuth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx)

If you want to keep the UI responsive in the face of lots of small updates you can either:

- Schedule items at a lower priority, which is nice and easy - but not so good if you need a certain priority
- Store updates in your own queue and enqueue them and have each operation you run Invoke the next item from your queue as it's last step.

### The bigger picture

It's worth stepping back a bit and looking at the bigger picture as well.

If you separately dump 3000 items into the UI in succession, what's that going to do for the user? At best they are going to be running a monitor with a refresh rate of 100Hz, probably lower. I find that frame rates of 10 per second are more than adequate for most purposes.

Not only that, human beings supposedly can't handle more than 5-9 bits of information in one go - so you might find better ways of aggregating and displaying information than updating so many things at once. For example, make use of master/detail views rather than showing everything on screen at once etc. etc.

Another option is to review how much work your UI update is causing. Some controls (I'm looking at you XamDataGrid) can have very lengthy measure/arrange layout operations. Can you simplify your animations? Use a simpler Visual tree? Think about the popular busy spinner that looks like circling dots - but really it's just changing their color. A great effect that is fairly cheap to achieve. It's worth profiling your application to see where time is going.

I would think about the overrall approach front-to-back as well. If you are reasonably certain you are going to get that many items to update at once, why not buffer them up and manage them in chunks? That would might have advantages all the way back to the source - which perhaps is on a server somewhere? In any case, Rx has some nice operators, like `Buffer` that can turn a stream of individual items into a larger lists - and it has overloads that can buffer by time *and* size together.

Comment: It's been a while now since I was working on this issue, but even changing priorities didn't seem to help. What I was hoping for was that my 3000 items with low priority would run interleaved with some higher priority render items. Unfortunately no matter what priorities I tried it seemed like my 3000 items were always processed first and no other items were interleaved :/

Comment: I also had this assumption with WPF, but it just doesn't seem to work that way. Instead of deeper investigation, I decided that the WPF dispatcher was far to precious to be doing anything on it that could be done on another thread. Rx is just so useful for this. I cant speak to ReactiveUI as I don't use it, but standard WPF+Rx works great.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `.SubscribeOn(TaskPoolScheduler.TaskPool)` to subscribe on a different thread?

Answer (score 0):

@Pedro Pombeiro has the right answer. 
The reason you are seeing the freezes on the UI is that you are queueing the work on the Dispatcher. This means the work will be done on the UI thread. You can think of the Dispatcher  as a message pump that is constant draining messages from each of its queues (which you can think of each of the priorities [SystemIdle, ApplicationIdle, ContextIdle, Background, Input, Loaded, Render, DataBind, Normal, Send])

Putting you work onto a different priority queue, does not make it run concurrently, just asynchronously.

To run your work on another thread using Rx, then use SubscribeOn as above. Remember to then schedule any updates to the UI back on to the Dispatcher with ObserveOn.

Comment: I still think it should be possible to do this single threaded using priorities. I wasn't successful though and fell back to a multi-threaded solution.